# The choropleth map and slider do not show the same date

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have a dataframe with countries, years and the country code.

Each additional column, such as "Annual CO2 Emission" can have a different start date in which data is available.

However, my main problem is that I cannot display the choropleth map and the slider as a common end date, e.g. 2021.
The slider is in 2021, the map when hovering is 1965 and the legend is in 2021 again.

So apparently the map isn't updating.

Does anyone have a solution? I would like to display the entire plot with the respective end date.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from ipywidgets import interactive, Dropdown

# Data Import: Load the Excel file into a DataFrame
file_path = "09_Outputs/main_data.xlsx"
df_main = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Fixed reference columns
fixed_columns = ['Entity', 'Year', 'Code']

# List of columns to visualize (excluding the fixed columns)
columns_to_visualize = [col for col in df_main.columns if col not in fixed_columns]

# Function to create the interactive choropleth map
def plot_choropleth(selected_column):
    # Determine the last available year for the selected column
    last_valid_year = df_main[df_main[selected_column].notna()]["Year"].max()
    
    # Create the choropleth map
    fig = px.choropleth(df_main,
                        locations='Code', 
                        color=selected_column,
                        hover_name='Entity', 
                        animation_frame='Year',
                        title=f"{selected_column} by Country",
                        color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma,
                        scope='world')
    
    # Set the size of the map
    fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=1000, height=600)
    
    # Set the starting year on the slider to the last available year for the selected column
    fig.layout.sliders[0].active = int(last_valid_year - df_main['Year'].min())
    
    fig.show()

# Dropdown menu: Column selection for visualization
dropdown = Dropdown(options=columns_to_visualize, description='Select Column:', value=columns_to_visualize[0])

# Interactive visualization
interactive_plot = interactive(plot_choropleth, selected_column=dropdown)
interactive_plot
```

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eavXw.png)

The goal is to have an interactive map like [ourworldindata](https://ourworldindata.org/co2-emissions).
And is the interactive bar also possible with the ranges? What is the name of this element?

[ourworldindata map as goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOOl9.png)